# how to count number of keys in firebase real time database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How do I count number of keys, with the help of firebase functions, in above case there are 3. I am using firebase real time database

Comment: That looks like Firestore to me 

Comment: nope real time db

Answer (score 10):

There is no separate count operation for Firebase Realtime Database. You'll have to download the entire snapshot of the parent node (`geoTag`) and then count the number of children in your application code.

How to do this, depends on the platform:

- On Android, call [`snapshot.getChildrenCount()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getChildrenCount()).
- On iOS, read the [`snapshot.childrenCount` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#childrencount).
- In JavaScript, read the [`snapshot.size` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.datasnapshot.md#datasnapshotsize)

If you have many children and all you need is the count, the above quickly becomes overly wasteful. In such cases, it's best to store the child count in a separate property yourself, and update it whenever you add/remove child nodes. Then you can read only the counter when you need that. There is even a sample [Cloud Function](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node-1st-gen/child-count)  that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have `geoTag` object locally to your application, you could just call:

```
Object.keys(geoTag).length
```